# How to run a java class with inner classes in it with command line?

Tags: java

I am really new in java and when I try to use inner class in a class, I can run it successfully in IntelliJ, but when I use the command line, there are something wrong

when I use command "java" and "javac" to the class which has no inner class, it works well, so how should I do to deal with it??

The command line I use:

```
johnMbp:courseWork athena$ javac MainFrame.java
johnMbp:courseWork athena$ ls
MainFrame.class
MainFrame$CheckAnswersListener.class    
MainFrame$ResetListener.class   
MainFrame.java  
johnMbp:courseWork athena$ java MainFrame
```

then it tells me that it can not load or find the main class MainFrame

Comment: Try with `java -cp . MainFrame`.

Comment: @Pshemo not work, still the same problem

Comment: @Pshemo That's the default. Why are you recommending it?

Comment: @user207421 I've seen cases when `.` wasn't part of predefined classpath settings and needed to be explicitly set via `-cp .`. IMO it was worth to check it.

Comment: Do you have a `public static void main(String[] args) { ... }` method in the MainFrame.java class ?

Comment: @VictorGubin That would cause `Main method not found in class ...` error, not `Could not find or load main class ...`.

Comment: @VictorGubin yes, I have

Comment: You have to execute your `MainFrame` class from the top of your project hierarchy (aka root)

Comment: I can run it successfully, when I remove "package innerClassDemo;", why??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a `package` statement at the beginning of your file? If so, you need to have the class in the same directory structure as the package. For example, if the package is `com.example.assignment1`, then you should have a directory `com/example/assignment1` and then use the command

```
java com.example.assignment1.MainFrame
```

Comment: @yuhan, you said "when I use command "java" and "javac" to the class which has no inner class, it works well".  Was that right?

Comment: @SteveSmith To the class which has no inner class, I did not add "package" statement and I did not notice it